# Wordpress homepage hangs in IE browsers

Tags: customization

Anyone has any insight why http://www.quantnet.com loads fine in FF, Chrome but hangs in IE for 20 seconds or more?

I have been hunting down the problem but reach an end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a waterfall chart showing your page load.](http://www.webpagetest.org/result/110208_NE_3HWF/1/details/)

Your page loads in 3.1 seconds, but doesn't fire the document.ready event for another 27 seconds.

Aside from various room for optimization (you might split your .pngs across domains to make them load faster, for example) what this waterfall chart shows that it's not the page that is hung but the page content.

It is not WordPress or WordPress content, rather the page your WordPress content is on or some 3rd party plugin (for example) failing to put scripts in the footer. This is probably in part because of the heavy usage of images without image sprites, but likely there is also some JavaScript blocking the onload event.

I'd start with the JavaScript, debugging using a tool like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

Comment: thank you, sir. From the waterfall, it appears the problem is with IE unable to rend png images in fancybox.css. I googled and found the solution is to use absolute path instead of relative. It seems to work now.

Comment: Here is link to that reference <http://www.safiweb.co.ke/how-to-fix-jquery-fancybox-1-3-1-close-and-nav-buttons-not-displaying-in-ie>

Comment: Great! Since this seems to have worked out for you would you terribly mind marking this answer as correct?